# Javascript ternary operator syntax not understood

Tags: javascript

I want to understand this please, someone can write as (if/else/elseif) statments ???

```
lists[list === 'todo' ? 'done' : 'todo'].appendChild(task);
```

Thanks

Comment: Strange logic – if something has status „todo” add it to „done” otherwise add to „todo”

Comment: I think ternary operator duplicate is at least a half of the OP's confusion. Mostly it's about combination of bracket notation with ternary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite it as:

```
if (list === 'todo') {
    lists.done.appendChild(task);
}
else {
    lists.todo.appendChild(task);
}
```

The thing here is that you can access any property of the object via [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), which allows variables and expressions resolving to a property name. Thus, `lists.done` is equivalent to `lists['done']` but with the later you can use expressions to calculate key name. This is what you have in the original example.

Comment: This works , thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
if (list === 'todo') {
    lists['done'].appendChild(task);
else {
    lists['todo'].appendChild(task);
}
```